# OrientDB JDBC connector pool on Tomcat 7

Tags: java, jdbc, tomcat7, jndi, orientdb

I added "orientdb-jdbc-2.2.20.jar" in lib folder.

I added the following in conf/server.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/orientdb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        driverclassname="com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcDriver"
        url="jdbc:orient:remote:localhost/GratefulDeadConcerts"
        username="admin" password="admin"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
        maxactive="20" maxidle="10" maxwait="-1"/>
```

In conf/web.xml I added

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>Archive Database</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/orientdb</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

In webapps/[all the web applications]/META_INF/context.xml I added

```
<ResourceLink global="jdbc/orientdb" name="jdbc/orientdb" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

I set the JNDI Name for the new data source as:

```
java:comp/env/jdbc/orientdb
```

but I get this error:

```
    'org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
AVVERTENZA: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.sql.SQLException
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:730)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:664)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:156)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:560)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:245)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:141)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:848)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:836)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceLinkFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceLinkFactory.java:152)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:848)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:836)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:836)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:836)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:156)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at it.eng.spagobi.api.v2.DataSourceResource.testDataSource(DataSourceResource.java:386)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
    ... 63 more'
```

How can I solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the attributes of your resource definition.

You used `driverclassname` but the correct attribute name is `driverClassName` (see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html).

Same for `maxidle`, `maxactive` etc.

Comment: @vincentdj did you change the url attribute?

Answer (score 2):

If you add the jar to the classpath manually instead of using a dependencies management system such as maven or gradle, please download  orientdb-jdbc-2.2.20-all.jar :

http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/orientechnologies/orientdb-jdbc/2.2.20/

This is a fat jar that includes all the part of orientDB needed by the JDBC driver itself.

Comment: I solved the error by adding orientdb-jdbc-2.2.20-all.jar, but while attemping to load the datasource, I get `HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.RuntimeException: Impossible to initialize physical model`. Maybe I have to add others part of orientDB in the /lib folder?

Comment: The jar should be enough. Post the complete stack trace and describe your application stack. The more you detail, the more I can help.

Comment: I posted the complete stack trace as answer. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: take the latest snapshot here: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/orientechnologies/orientdb-jdbc/2.2.21-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Just FYI, we are going to release 2.2.21 in a few days with this fix. And then I will improve the support of database metadata  in the driver

Comment: I tested it and it overcomes the error that I posted, but another error occured. I haven't yet understood what the cause is. I get an error while generating model. It generates a datamart.jar empty. So, when I try to create a DataSet through Qbe, it returns "Impossible to create engine instance for datamart [OrientDB_Model_Grafo]. The root cause of the error is: zip file is empty".

Comment: I really don't know knowage works, but you can provide the stack trace it would be great. And maybe you can open an issue, so I can manage it better.